# Failed to set up deployment source for web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I'm having a problem setting up a deployment source on an Azure Web App for my Visual Studio Team Services account.

I had just reorganised my solution - added a new project and changed the root directory of my git repo to be the parent folder of the old root folder (I used to have my solution & project in the same folder, which was my git root, but now I have .\solution\ & .\solution\project1 & .\solution\project2, with .\solution now being my git root).

Continuous deployment had been setup via my Visual Studio Team Services account, and was working fine, but after this reorganisation it stopped working. I tried deleting and recreating the Azure Web Site, and also re-created the VS Team Services project, but that made no difference.

When I attempt to set the Deployment Source for my Web App in the portal, it fails with the following error:

```
Failed to set up deployment source for web app my-web-app(Staging), 
using Visual Studio Team Services. Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' 
operation failed with System.InvalidOperationException: Vso GetRepository: 
Cannot find repository 
https://my_account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/my_repo_name
at 
Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.<GetRepository>d__3f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__6.MoveNext().
```

Comment: Related issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a703772-aa2a-45cc-911f-09eedeb2b94e/failed-deployment-for-web-app-using-vsts?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Also, can you check whether you're still able to deploy with a solution that doesn't have your recent change? That would help identify whether that's really the cause, vs some unrelated Azure/VSTS issue.

Comment: Yes @david, I tried it again with a single project solution and it worked fine. The problem seems to be with multi-project solutions. As I mentioned in a comment below yesterday, there is a workaround using a custom deployment script when using the classic portal, using the new portal it looks like it may be possible to get it working by using an ARM template (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-complex-application-predictably.md), but I've not tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the Deployment Source in the new portal. You can try to set up deployment from source control on Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Doing this allowed me to link the Web App to the VS Online repo, but it would then fail on deployment (with a pretty uninformative error during MSBUILD). I think the problem must be that it doesn't support solutions with multiple projects, and I'll probably need to create a custom deployment script.

This shouldn't be required because the solution file knows which project is the primary 'start-up' project, but it mustn't be handling this scenario.

Comment: See this for an example: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/azure-web-sites-git-deploy-for-multiple-project-solutions